# tkinter app spins 2 windows utilizing MVC

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on simple application trying to utilize MVC pattern. The problem I found (which I predict is a really silly one, but I lost my rubber duck) is two tkinter apps are created where I expect just a single one. Moreover, second one is instantiated but is not visible what made me mad initially as I didn't know it exists ;-)

Smells to me like another Tk() instance is being created, but donno when, where and why.

[image]

When I replace `root = Main()` with `root = tk.Tk()` in AppDelegte everything works like a charm and just one app window is created, as intended.

App is created on following code:

**App delegate**

```python
from controller.main import Main

root = Main()

root.mainloop()
```

**Main controller**

```python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from view.actual_readings import ActualReadings


class Main(tk.Tk):

    actual_readings = ActualReadings(None)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        main_frame = ttk.Frame(self, padding="25")
        main_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.actual_readings.master = main_frame
        self.actual_readings.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

**Readings view**

```python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class ActualReadings(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        header = ttk.Label(self, text="header text", font="TkFixedFont", padding="75 25 75 10")
        current_value_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text="current value",
                                         font="TkFixedFont")
        current_value_val = ttk.Label(self, text="here comes reading", font="TkFixedFont")

        header.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
        current_value_lbl.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)
        current_value_val.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when you create `Main` (a `Tk()` instance), its class member `actual_readings` is created first.  Since its parent is `None` which causes a default instance of Tk() being created.  So there will be two `Tk()` instances.

To fix the issue, you should create `actual_readings` inside `__init__()` function:

```
class Main(tk.Tk):
    actual_readings = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        main_frame = ttk.Frame(self, padding='25')
        main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        if self.actual_readings is None:
            self.actual_readings = ActualReadings(main_frame)
            self.actual_readings.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: That's a valuable answer, haven't found that info anywhere across the docs so far. Kudos!